# SQL Server : trigger FOR DELETE

Tags: sql-server, trigger, delete

I want to create a trigger, which **does not** delete a customer if his name is `Peter`. How can I do that?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCUSTOMER ON customer
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT name FROM deleted) not like 'Peter'
    BEGIN
        delete from customer where name = (select name from deleted);
    END
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Rollback the DELETE in case you're deleting the row "Peter". You do this with an AFTER trigger. Be aware that it will rollback the whole transaction in case yuo're deleting multiple rows among which at least one is "Peter".

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_CUSTOMER_DEL ON customer
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM deleted
        WHERE name = 'Peter'
    )
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        THROW 50001, 'Cannot delete Peter', 1;
    END
END;
```

2) You override the way SQL Server does DELETEs on the table, using an INSTEAD OF trigger. In this case, you silently ignore DELETEs for the row "Peter".

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_CUSTOMER_IO_DEL ON customer
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE c
    FROM customer AS c
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
        ON c.customer_id = d.customer_id
    WHERE d.name <> 'Peter';

END;
```

Which one is best for you highly depends on your business logic.

Comment: thanks, it works! But the syntax have some errors. I will comment my trigger.

Comment: Just for everyone: beware if you have SQL Server < 2012, you won't be able to use `THROW`. Instead you can use `RAISERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

That Trigger worked.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCustomer ON customer
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE 
    FROM customer
        WHERE customer.ID IN (Select ID from deleted where name != 'Peter')
END;
```

Comment: This syntax will work only when you delete a single customer, it will fail when you try to delete multiple rows at once. Change `customer.ID =` to `customer.ID IN`

Comment: Also, don't forget to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of the trigger body, otherwise many providers will complain about `@@ROWCOUNT` being altered by the trigger code.

Comment: And don't forget to add some explanation.  Without it, your post was automatically flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

To not delete records (for auditing purposes, as per OP's post), but to flag the record deleted, and change your view to reflect this, I do the following.

Create the trigger as per the above, but alter it into an UPDATE statement...

```
USE [yourdatabase];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER declencheur_suppression
ON synt_examen
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
   UPDATE t
   SET t.Status = 0
   FROM Etudiant AS t
      INNER JOIN deleted d ON t.ID = d.ID
GO
```

Of course you will need to add another column called '`Status`' and default it to 1 for ACTIVE (or non deleted). When it's 0, it implies it's been deleted.

To reflect that, change your view to have a `WHERE` clause such as `WHERE Etudiant = 1`.

I prefer this method because **physically deleting records** should be avoided as much as possible, for good DBA practice.

Answer (score 0):

Skapa en trigger, som vid delete från en tabell kopierar data till en history tabell. Men, även ej deletade rader kopieras. Eller bara översta raden an de som har samma namn på kund.

Hur skriver jag en korrekt trigger på after delete?

Comment: Sorry, this is an English only site.